# Oracle SQL: How to display the earliest date after min(to_char(birthdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))

Tags: sql, oracle, date, max, min

I need to convert the birthdates in my table to 'MM/DD/YYYY' format and when I do that the min(birthdate) is just the date where the month is the smallest number and the max(birthdate) is the date where the month is the largest number. How do I make it so it displays the dates where the year is the smallest and largest, but still in the desired date format?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're querying `min(to_char(birthdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))`. As you've seen, when you do this you'll get the minimum calculated by lexicographic ordering. Instead, you should apply the formatting **after** applying min/max:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(MIN(birthdate), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_CHAR(MAX(birthdate), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: I'm using Oracle and it says 'invalid number of arguments' when I switch the order to to_char and min

Comment: @Jonnyjohnson I messed up the parenthesis there, sorry. See my edited answer for a sample that should work

Answer (score 1):

Just [use](http://rextester.com/HNSC84713) the following

```
with t(birthdate) as
(
 select trunc(sysdate) as birthdate from dual union all    
 select trunc(sysdate)-300 from dual union all    
 select trunc(sysdate)-600 from dual union all
 select trunc(sysdate)-900 from dual
)
select to_char(birthdate,'MM/DD/YYYY') as birthdate
  from t;

BIRTHDATE
----------
09/16/2018
11/20/2017
01/24/2017
03/30/2016


with t(birthdate) as
(
 select trunc(sysdate) as birthdate from dual union all    
 select trunc(sysdate)-300 from dual union all    
 select trunc(sysdate)-600 from dual union all
 select trunc(sysdate)-900 from dual
)
select to_char(min(birthdate),'MM/DD/YYYY') as min_birthdate,
       to_char(max(birthdate),'MM/DD/YYYY')  as max_birthdate
  from t;

MIN_BIRTHDATE   MAX_BIRTHDATE
-------------   -------------
  03/30/2016      09/16/2018
```

where you're applying the min/max conversion first, and then formatting with respect to the displaying style you wish.